# laravel problem, @foreach and var_dump question

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade, var-dump

i'm having a problem with the @foreach in a blade.view

```
<SELECT  id= "chosen" type="text" class="form-control @error('chosen') is-invalid @enderror" name='chosen' style="width: 300px">

   @foreach($tables  as $chosen)
    <option value="{{ $chosen }}" > {{ $chosen }}</option>
   @endforeach

   </SELECT>


{{ var_dump($chosen) }}
```

in this dropdown menu the var_dump() does not print the value of what i choose, just the last row of the foreach, how can i print the data i choose in the menu?

Comment: Remember that PHP is a pre-processor and runs before the page is sent to the browser. Any changes made on the page would need to be handed by javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP runs from server and sent rendered html to client, so you cant access selected value in dropdown.
you can use [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) in browser to get current selected value.

check this:

```
$('#chosen').on('change', function() {
  alert( this.value );
});
```

or

```
var selectedItem = $("#chosen").children("option:selected").val();
alert("You have selected the item- " + selectedItem);
```

Comment: how should i put this inside my blade?

Comment: its not depends to blade. Do the same with blade as you do with html. just put this codes inside  a <script> tag next to where jquery included in page.

Comment: ok now it's more clear, but the alert appear just when i go to the page for the first time, what if i want to print dinamically the selected row (i need that for a later storing)